# get data from node-sqlite using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, ecmascript-6, promise

Can somebody show some good way using `Promises` with node-sqlite?

For example I'm trying to rewrite such code to avoid **callback-hell**
and get empty variables

```
tableRows = []
columns = []    

db.all(`... query`, params, (err, medics) => {
   medics.forEach((medic) => {
        db.all(`some other query`, {$id: medic.id}, (err, amounts) => {
              tableRows.push(amounts)
            })
        }
   }).all(`another query`, (err, result) => {
        columns = result
   })

console.log(tableRows, columns)
```

Can somebody help? 
Only node-sqlite please, no ORM or sqlite-based libs.

Answer (score -1):

If you can transpile your code or if you are using Node 7.6+, you can use async/await

```
(async function() {

   tableRows = []
    columns = []    

    try {

        const medics = await db.all(`... query`, params); 
        medics.forEach((medic) => {
            const amounts = await db.all(`some other query`, {$id: medic.id});
            tableRows.push(amounts);
        });

       const result = db.all(`another query`);
       columns = result;
       console.log(tableRows, columns);
   }

   catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
   }
})();
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work cause `db.all` returns `db` instanse for chaining like `db.all(query).all(query).run(query)......` Maybe another suggestion?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with node-sqlite. As long as the operation returns a promise, you can always await on that object. Let's say `medics = await db.all(...)`. Then you can do `await medics.all(...)`